# Connecting to DBus from emacs daemon

Tags: emacs, dbus, emacs24, auctex

I recently tried to set up AucTeX SyncTeX with evince under GNU Emacs 24.4. From an ordinary emacs session it work oput of the box after activating `TeX-source-correlate-mode`, but under my standard Daemon session Dbus refuses to work properly. `TeX-Evince-sync-view` fails with a DBus 'no conncetion' error, so I tried `M-: (dbus-init-bus :system)` but that returns `((:signal :system "org.freedesktop.DBus.Local" "Disconnected") (nil "/org/freedesktop/DBus/Local" dbus-handle-bus-disconnect))`

and `M-: dbus-init-bus :session` fails accordingly with 'no connection'.

Does anyone know how to get DBus running properly under Emacs in Daemon mode?

Comment: How do you solved that? For me, neither setting $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS on Emacs works. Only works if I setup this externally before I call `emacs --daemon`, which is a big problem since my emacs daemon starts before X server (I use a OpenRC service)

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to D-Bus from Emacs, it must know where the respective dbus-daemon resides. Usually, it knows it via the environment variable $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS. So set this variable in your daemonized Emacs before you call (dbus-init-bus :session) or alike